# With Android OS 4.x is there a way to restore iPhone-like list navigation when drilling down into a sub-list?

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I just upgraded my Nexus S operating system from 2.3 to 4.0.3 ("Ice Cream Sandwich"). I've been developing an app with MonoDroid 4.0 and noticed a change in the transitions between ListViews. I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed it and if there's a way to restore the 2.3 type of transition between activities.

In my app I've got a DashboardMain activity that has a ListView that contains several items.

[image]

When the user taps on one of the items in the list I start another activity using this code in a ListViewItemClick() method in the DashboardMain activity.

```
switch (item.Command)
{
    case "Navigate"
        Intent navigate = new Intent(this, typeof(DashboardNavigate));
        StartActivity(navigate);
        break;
    case "Collect"
        Intent collect = new Intent(this, typeof(DashboardCollect));
        StartActivity(collect);
        break;
    default:
        // Toast display code here for when Browse, Map, or Status are selected
        break; 
}
```

In 2.3, when either Navigate or Collect were tapped, a new activity was started and the DashboardMain list would "slide" to off the left of the screen, exposing the new activities' user interface (in each case another list of items).

[image]  [image]

This matches how iPhone list navigation works - the parent list disappears off the left side of the screen when you drill down into an item to see its detail.

In 4.0.3 the behavior is different. The user interface for the DashboardNavigate or DashboardCollect activities appears over the parent list. It looks like the sub-list is being "pushed onto" the parent list, obscuring it.

Has anyone else noticed this change or am I just imagining things? Is it a system-level change or is there a way to get back to the iPhone-like list navigation when transitioning between MonoDroid activities?

Thanks in advance.